# DataSource not getting injected in Spring 3

Tags: java, annotations, jdbctemplate, spring-jdbc

I'm new to spring, so please bear with me.

I tried configuring my app using annotations and java. However, data source is not getting injected into my dao impl.

I have a properties file which maintains 3 different configs(dev,uat,prd) and these are accessed via **CommonConfig**.

I am getting below **error**-

```
Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException: Property 'dataSource' is required for bean 'jdbcClientFundDao'
```

**DAO-**

```
package com.globeop.goreporting.gonavpack.persistence.dao;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public interface ClientFundDao {

    public List<String> getClientsForUser(String user);

    public ArrayList<String> getFundsForClient(String client);

}
```

**DAO Implementer-**

```
package com.globeop.goreporting.gonavpack.persistence.dao.impl;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Required;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import com.globeop.goreporting.gonavpack.persistence.dao.ClientFundDao;

@Repository
public class JdbcClientFundDao implements ClientFundDao {

    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Required    // tried @Autowired also
    public void setDataSource(DataSource datasource) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(datasource);
    }

    public List<String> getClientsForUser(String user) {
        List<String> clients = jdbcTemplate.queryForList("select distinct ClientShortName from Client where IsActiveFlag = ?", String.class, 1);
        return clients;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getFundsForClient(String client) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
}
```

**DataScource-**

```
package com.globeop.goreporting.gonavpack.persistence.datasource;

import org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import com.globeop.goreporting.gonavpack.model.CommonConfig;

@Configuration
public class DataSourceForClientFund {

    private static final String driverClassName = CommonConfig.DB_PARAMETERMAP_DRIVER;
    private static final String url = CommonConfig.DB_PARAMETERMAP_URL;
    private static final String dbUsername = CommonConfig.DB_PARAMETERMAP_USER;
    private static final String dbPassword = CommonConfig.DB_PARAMETERMAP_PWD;

    @Bean
    public static BasicDataSource getDataSource() {
        BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(driverClassName);
        dataSource.setUrl(url);
        dataSource.setUsername(dbUsername);
        dataSource.setPassword(dbPassword);
        return dataSource;
    }

}
```

**WebApplication Context (NavSummaryServlet-context.xml)-**

```
<!-- Contains @Controller, @RequestMapping, view resolver, etc  -->
<context:component-scan base-package="com.globeop.goreporting.gonavpack.webconfigs" />
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

**Application Context (NavSummaryApplication-context.xml)-**

```
<!-- Contains DAO, DAO impl, and DataSource beans -->
<context:annotation-config/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.globeop.goreporting.gonavpack.persistence" />
```

**web.xml-**

```
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>NavSummaryServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/goNavPackServlet/NavSummaryServlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>NavSummaryServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/navSummary.jsp</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/goNavPackApp/NavSummaryApplication-context.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>
```

Comment: Have you read about `ApplicationContext`? That's your IoC container.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Yes I did read about it(servlet-context.xml), configuring the DataSource over there is turning out to be tricky.. for me.

Comment: If you don't want to do it with XML, you can do it in java since Spring 3.0. Read [this chapter](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-java) in the documentation and you're all set.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I went through the doc and made changes in my code(updated above), but a new problem new, can u correct me ?

Comment: I would suggest creating a `@Bean` method for the `JdbcTemplate` by passing in the `DataSource` created from your other `@Bean` method. You can then `@Autowired` that `JdbcTemplate`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis can you paste the code as an answer ? Will be easier for me and I'll accept it, increasing your reputation ;)

Comment: Just added it. Did it solve your issue?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis No, jdbcTemplate is still not getting injected. Everything is working fine when I test from a Main() method and initialize jdbcTemplate manually.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to initialize the `JdbcTemplate` in your class. The whole point of an IoC container is to have it do that for you.

So add a `@Bean` method to create it. (Also, don't make your methods static, it's not needed in this case)

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "the.name.of.your.package")
public class DataSourceForClientFund {

    private static final String driverClassName = CommonConfig.DB_PARAMETERMAP_DRIVER;
    private static final String url = CommonConfig.DB_PARAMETERMAP_URL;
    private static final String dbUsername = CommonConfig.DB_PARAMETERMAP_USER;
    private static final String dbPassword = CommonConfig.DB_PARAMETERMAP_PWD;

    @Bean
    public BasicDataSource getDataSource() {
        BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(driverClassName);
        dataSource.setUrl(url);
        dataSource.setUsername(dbUsername);
        dataSource.setPassword(dbPassword);
        return dataSource;
    }


    @Bean
    public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate() {    
        final JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate();

        jdbcTemplate.setDataSource(getDataSource()); // notice this is calling the other Bean method
        jdbcTemplate.afterPropertiesSet();

        return jdbcTemplate;
    }
}
```

You can then `@Autowired` or `@Inject` the `JdbcTemplate` directly.

In your `@Repository`

```
@Repository
public class JdbcClientFundDao implements ClientFundDao {
    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
    ...
}
```

In a `@Controller`

```
@Controller
public class YourController {
    @Autowired
    private ClientFundDao clientFundDao; // Spring will inject an `JdbcClientFundDao` instance
}
```

[This Spring documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-java) should explain how these configurations are done.

Comment: Still getting error, I've removed the setter method in JdbcClientFundDao, and added annotation @Autowired before `private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;`.

Comment: Oh you need `@ComponentScan`. Let me update Add that annotation to your `@Configuration` class and add the name of the package in which your class `JdbcClientFundDao` is in. You should remove your web application context component scan.

Comment: How can I remove my web application context component scan ? My viewResolver & handlerMapping config are in other (parent)packages.

Comment: @kaustavdatta I would recommend you at least move them to outside the package or be more specific. A ComponentScan searches recursively through all subpackages. You don't want your web context to generate components that are supposed to be in your application context.

Comment: I think I am getting the error because I am accessing the DAO(ClientFundDao) in my controller in a wrong way - `ClientFundDao dao = new JdbcClientFundDao(); List<String> clients = dao.getClientsForUser(user); model.addAttribute("clients", clients);`. Does my DAO(ClientFundDao) need to be defined as a bean ?

Comment: The Dao has to be injected into the Controller. If you do `ClientFundDao dao = new JdbcClientFundDao();`, then you just have an object. It's not managed by Spring and so nothing is autowired into it.

Comment: You have a `@Repository` class `JdbcClientFundDao`. If you add a `@Autowired private JdbcClientFundDao jdbcClientFundDao` in your Controller, you can then use that dao everywhere.

Comment: But then wont my interface i.e. `ClientFundDao` become useless if I directly access its implementer i.e `JdbcClientFundDao` ?

Comment: Yes, sorry, wasn't paying attention. Use `ClientFundDao`.

Comment: So should I annotate `public interface ClientFundDao` with `@Repository` ? If not, how do I access `ClientFundDao` ?

Comment: I've added what it should look like in my answer. Don't annotate the interface, annotate the implementation. `@Repository` is also a `@Component` so generate will an instance of it in the application context that will be available for injection/autowiring.

Comment: `2013-08-09 12:48:17 - main        - ERROR [DispatcherServlet:467]: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'homeController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.globeop.goreporting.gonavpack.persistence.dao.ClientFundDao com.globeop.goreporting.gonavpack.webconfigs.HomeController.clientFundDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionExcep..`

Comment: I think your contexts aren't setup correctly. Can you add them to your question?

Comment: `@Autowired private ClientFundDao clientFundDao;` in my controller is throwing the above error, but this is working `private ClientFundDao clientFundDao = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(JdbcClientFundDao.class, DataSourceForClientFund.class).getBean(ClientFundDao.class);` in my controller, is this fine ?

Comment: I think it's a bad idea to get the bean that way. Show us your contexts by updating your question.

Comment: Updated my question. Also note that I have not used any annotation in my DAO interface. i.e `public interface ClientFundDao`